# Use single or compact spacing in side notes

Tags: footnotes, line-spacing, sidenotes, snotez

I have a document that by default uses double spacing. This is fine for the main text, but side notes use lots of space.

**How can I disable double spacing for margin side notes?**

```
\documentclass[english,aps,preprint]{revtex4} %preprint implied double spacing
\usepackage[footnote=true]{snotez} %footnotes as sidenotes
\begin{document}

bla \footnote{sidenote sidenote sidenote sidenote sidenote} %sidenotes use double spacing!! they use a lot of space

\end{document}
```

If possible I prefer a solution that changes the style of the side note without adding commands to the side note.

---

I realized that I was using `\marginpar` for the side notes, not `\footnote`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reset the `\linespread` in the side notes:

```
\documentclass[english,aps,preprint]{revtex4} %preprint implied double spacing
\usepackage[footnote=true]{snotez} %footnotes as sidenotes

\setsidenotes{text-format+=\linespread{1}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

bla \footnote{sidenote sidenote sidenote sidenote sidenote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I realized that I was using `\marginpar` for the side notes, not `\footnote/snotez`.